# PhpStorm: how to get all methods from other class in autocomplete (Zend2 ViewHelper)?

Tags: php, autocomplete, zend-framework2, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have a problem (this is not really a problem) with PhpStorm. I'm writing in pure PHP and HTML in Zend2 Views and I need to get autocomplete (<kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>) methods from all Zend ViewHelpers.

I created `CustomPhpRender` class that inherits from real Zend `PhpRenderer`.

I cannot find a solution, how can I virtually add all methods from e.g. Form ViewHelper in one line (in PHPDoc). Instead of this, of course, I can write all `@method` class for every method I need to get in autocomplete.

Have you got any solution how can I do it?

Comment: You can try `@mixin ClassName` -- in theory should work. P.S. This may work in PhpStorm only.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, phpStorm will not auto-write the required functions for you. It will give you warnings are far as what is required. I believe it will auto-complete the function declaration for you when you go to declare a required function. It will offer a suggestion and then you hit tab. I've extended classes multiple times, and this is how it has always done it for me.